# PayPal REST API app, why multiple Return URLs

Tags: api, rest, paypal, returnurl

I am wondering why in the REST API app it is possible to store more than one Return URL.

After the buyer have approved the order, the script can only return to one URL. So why should I store some more URLs?

Some more details:

PayPal provieds a REST API app for processing a payment. In the PayPal developer dashboard you can do the configuration with several settings for this app. One of the settings is the "Return URL":

"Return URL- Users are redirected to this URL after live transactions. Allow up to three hours for the change to take effect."

This site gives a good introduction:
https://www.angelleye.com/how-to-create-paypal-app

Take a look at step 5.

What is it good for, to store more than 1 URL?

My problem:

The payment transaction works fine till I want to approve the payment. Then the paypal script shows for a short moment a message that I will be redirected to the shop-site. But it reloads the PayPal-approve-page again.

I suppose there is something wrong with my URL? Maybe a spezial syntax is required?

My Links is so:
https://radl.mysite.de/tiki/tiki-index.php

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide an example or reference of what you are talking about

Answer (score 2):

Drew from [www.angelleye.com](http://www.angelleye.com) gave me the key tip. (Thanx a lot)

In the field "Return-URL" every URL I want to use have to be there in order to use it. A better name would be "Potential Return-URLs".

The actual return URL have to be placed in the "create order" request.

The correct JSON for a order creation is:

```
{"intent": "CAPTURE", 
        "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": "19.00"}
        }],
        "application_context":
        {
            "brand_name": "BobShop",
            "landing_page": "LOGIN",
            "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING",
            "return_url": "https://www.mysite.de",
            "cancel_url": "https://www.mysite.de"
        }
       }
```

A "show order" request does onyl respond the "brand_name". The rest of the "application_context" is not responded by teh request!